# windows 8 data lost while installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu-14.04, data-recovery

I had windows operating system. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 operating system by over writing windows 8. But I lost 5 GB of data which was very important.

I tried test disk tool to recover data.But it couldn't recover the data.

[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Data_Recovery_Examples)

kindly help to solve this problem.

Is it possible for a linux data recovery tool to recover data from NTFS partition?

thanks in advance

---

Comment: Restore from your regular backups.

Comment: There are no regular backups

Comment: But you said it's important data. Important data is backed up.

Comment: But I niether took any backups nor installed backup software which would automatically backup the data

Comment: This is off-topic, should be on http://superuser.com/

Comment: See this answer for how to image your drive and how to restore data using my NTFS file system reconstruction software: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu right on top the W8 partition the chances are high that some of that data is lost.

Before you do much and destroy even more data:
1)Get yourself another machine.
2) Attach the disk to it and copy it with DD as backup or for extraction purposes
3) Mount the Copy and analyze it with SleuthKit and Autopsy.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery